# Creating an array of HashMaps with Arraylist values

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections, hashmap

So I'm working on my final project for my college Java II course and had the idea to make a sort of game developer Item Inventory. The basic idea is that a subclass, say a Gun subclass of a weapon superclass, would first allow a developer to make a specific object of that class for a game they were making. They would then be able to take that object they created and store it in an ItemInventory class which would retain all the details of that particular object (i.e. In the case of a Gun object, it's type, magazine size, damage, etc.) and store it in a collection of that type. My idea for the creation of the ItemInventory would be to create an array of HashMaps. The HashMaps would each contain a key in the form of the String weaponType, (say I made a gun and assigned the type field "Sniper Rifle") and a value in the form of an ArrayList. That way I would be able to go through the array, find the weapon type that matches that of the object I created, and store it in a specific ArrayList for that weapon type.

```
    /**
 * A class to make an in-game firearm object
 *
 * @author Matt
 * @version 12/4/2020
 */
public class Gun extends WeaponClass
{
    //field declarations
    private int rounds; 
    private String rateOfFire; 
    private int magazine; 
    
    
     * Constructor
     
    public Gun(String weaponName, String weaponType, double damageAmt, String rarity, int rounds, String rateOfFire, int magazine){
        super(weaponName, weaponType, damageAmt, rarity);
        this.rounds = rounds; 
        this.rateOfFire = rateOfFire;
        this.magazine = magazine; 
    }
    
    
     * Method to assign the number of rounds for the firearm
     
    public void setRounds(int rounds){
        this.rounds = rounds; 
    }
    
    
     * Method to assign the rate of fire for the fireArm
     
    public void setRateOfFire(String rateOfFire){
        this.rateOfFire = rateOfFire; 
    }
    
    
     * Method to assign the magazine size of the firearm 
     
    public void setMagSize(int magazine){
        this.magazine = magazine;
    }
    
    
     * Method to print info about the firearm 
     
    public void printGunInfo(){
        System.out.println(this); 
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    /*------------------------Accessor Methods-----------------------------*/ 
    
    
     * Method to get the number of rounds
     
    public int getRounds(){
        return rounds; 
    }
   
    
     * Method to get the rate of fire of the weapon 
     
    public String getRateFire(){
        return rateOfFire; 
    }
    
    
     * Method to return the magazine size of the weapon 
     
    public int getMagazine(){
        return magazine;
    }
    
    
     * Method to override toString()
     
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String fireArmString = super.toString() + "\nRounds: " + rounds + 
            "\nRate of Fire: " + rateOfFire + "\nMagazine Size: " + magazine;
        return fireArmString;
        
    }
}
```

The above shows the class code for the gun subclass, which was no problem to make.

```
import java.util.HashMap; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
/**
 * An item inventory 
 *
 * @author Matt
 * @version 12/14/2020
 */
public class ItemInventory
{
   //field Declarations
   private HashMap<String, ArrayList<WeaponClass>>[] weapons;
   
   
    * Constructor
    
   public ItemInventory(){
        weapons[7] = new HashMap<>();
    }
    
    
     * Method to set up the weaponArray
     
    public void setWeaponAray(){
        weapons[0] = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<WeaponClass>>();
        weapons[0].put("Sniper Rifle", ArrayList("SniperList"));
        
    }
    
}
```

And this shows where I'm at with the inventory. Right now it doesn't compile as in the put statement, it says it cannot find symbol - method ArrayList(java.lang.String). What I would like to know is am I on the right track here with the item inventory class? Or is there a better way to do this? Any additional advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much. :)
P.S. This is my first time making a post on here so my apologies if I appear to have made any formatting or etiquette errors/anything of the like.

EDIT: Got it compiling, don't know if it will work though.

```
/**
     * Method to set up the weaponArray so objects can be 
     * added to the correct list
     */
    public void setWeaponAray(){
        weapons[0] = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<WeaponClass>>();
        weapons[0].put("Sniper Rifle", new ArrayList<WeaponClass>());
        
        weapons[1] = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<WeaponClass>>(); 
        weapons[1].put("Shotgun", new ArrayList<WeaponClass>());
        
        weapons[2] = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<WeaponClass>>(); 
        weapons[2].put("Hand Gun", new ArrayList<WeaponClass>());
        
        weapons[3] = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<WeaponClass>>(); 
        weapons[3].put("Submachine Gun", new ArrayList<WeaponClass>());
        
        weapons[4] = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<WeaponClass>>(); 
        weapons[4].put("Katana", new ArrayList<WeaponClass>()); 
        
        weapons[5] = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<WeaponClass>>(); 
        weapons[5].put("Club", new ArrayList<WeaponClass>()); 
        
        weapons[6] = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<WeaponClass>>(); 
        weapons[6].put("Knife", new ArrayList<WeaponClass>());

        
    }
```

Comment: I didn't take a detailed look, I've seen some not minor details (you really need to go back to your books) but the error you are getting "`cannot find symbol - method ArrayList(java.lang.String)`" is exactly that, `ArrayList` class does not have a constructor with 1 element, you have to do `new ArrayList()` and then `add` the element... In this case it will also fail because you are declaring `ArrayList` to have `WeaponClass` elements and you are trying to add a `String` element/object/instance (`"SniperList"`)

Comment: @AleZalazar  So instead it would be something more like `weapons[0].put("Sniper Rifle", new ArrayList<WeaponClass>());` ? Additionally, if you wouldn't mind pointing out some of said not minor details, I'd be happy to go back and fix them, this is still kinda rough right now as I just try to get in functioning.

Comment: I'd rather say:
```List<WeaponClass> list = new ArrayList<WeaponClass>();

list.add(new Gun(... with all parameters here));

weapons[0].put("Sniper Rifle", list); ```